# IONIC 3: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: google is not defined ReferenceError

Tags: angular, google-maps, typescript, ionic3

How are you?. I am studying a Google Maps with Ionic 3 tutorial. I have done everything what is explained there, but when the project is launched, there is appearing this error. I have investigated A LOT, but nothing works. Thanks!.

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: google is not defined
ReferenceError: google is not defined
```

This is my code:

**home.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';

declare var google;

@IonicPage()
@Component({
selector: 'page-home',
templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    @ViewChild('map') mapElement:ElementRef;
    map: any;
    start = 'chicago, il';
    end = 'chicago, il';
    directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

    }

    ionViewLoad(){
        this.initMap();
    }

    initMap(){
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, 
    { 
            zoom: 7,
            center: {lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65}
    });

        this.directionsDisplay.setMap(this.map);
    }

    calculateAndDisplayRoute(){
        this.directionsService.route({
            origin: this.start,
            destination: this.end,
            travelMode: 'DRIVING',
        }, (response, status) => {
            if(status == 'OK'){
                this.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            }else{
                window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + 
        status);
            }
        });
        }

     }
```

Comment: is this a cordova plugin? are you running in a device?

Comment: No. Laptop browser. Yes, is a cordova plugin.

Comment: cordova plugins are not loaded with `ionic serve`. Use emulator/device

Comment: Ok. I am going to try on that way.

Comment: Link Google maps js SDK file in `index.html`.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you use HTTPS when loading javascript!

Change from this

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
```

To

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
```

Comment: Perfect answer!

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you are not using "async" and "defer" in your script when you are loading Google Maps API. If you are using these, please remove them. It'll work fine. Use it like this:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY"></script>
```

Please have a look at this issue posted on Ionic forum for detailed guidance:

[Issue posted on Ionic Forum](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/help-me-pls-javascript-google-map-not-work-some-time/125887/10)

Hope this will help you. 
Cheers!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to `declare` it as shown below where you didn't do that in your code.

```
declare var google: any;
```

About the same issue on [**Git repo**](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app/issues/293)

Comment: But didn't declare it as `any` @suraj

Comment: You need to use a `device`. `ionic cordova run android --prod --device`

Answer (score 0):

Even if you declare google, you have to 'wait' for the device to be loaded.

Have you tried to use `setTimeout()` ?

E.g.:

```
ionViewLoad(){
    setTimeout(()=>{ this.initMap(); },100);
}
```