# Google is not defined error in Ionic3

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework, maps, ionic3

I am using @agm/core for map in Ionic3 project.
I want to get lat long from Address, I tried this code for that.

```
 let _address= this.cancellation.street+','+this.cancellation.city +', '+this.cancellation.state;
  // let _address= 'Okara, Pakistan';
  console.log(_address);
  var me = this;
  let geo = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  geo.geocode( { 'address': _address}, function(results, status) {
   console.log("LatLngFromAddress:",results[0].geometry.location.lat() +'/'+results[0].geometry.location.lng());
   me.markerLocation.lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
   me.markerLocation.lng =results[0].geometry.location.lng();

   me.location.lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
   me.location.lng =results[0].geometry.location.lng();
   me.loadAPIWrapper(me.map);
 });
```

but I get an error of Google not defined, 
Even i declared a variable on Top also

```
declare var google: any;
```

i read from following , but unable to get fixed it.
[IONIC 3: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: google is not defined ReferenceError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46313492/ionic-3-uncaught-in-promise-referenceerror-google-is-not-defined-referencee)

I also tried using typing

```
typings install dt~google.maps --global
```

But this also doesn't not work for me.
can you help me please.

Comment: Can you provide the code where you define google?

Comment: I recall needing to wait until Platform.ready() event before using google.  Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, in my case, the reason was because the asynchronism, the markers tried to appear before loading the map, I fixed it by implementing the "ngAfterViewInit" hook and using a subscription to an EventEmmiter like this:

```
import { AgmMap } from '@agm/core';

export class MyAGMContainerComponent{
@ViewChild('myMap') myMap : AgmMap;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.myMap.mapReady.subscribe(
  event => {
    this.loadMarkers();
  });
}

loadMarkers(){ // code for markers //}
```

And the html like this:

```
<agm-map #myMap>
  <agm-marker>
...
  </agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```